# Update bindings in Swixml2

Tags: java, swing, swixml

I've got a dialog defined in [SwiX<sup>ml</sup>](http://www.swixml.org/) xml that binds with a property on the corresponding bean for the dialog.

```
:
<label text="Project Files Location"/>
<textfield id="tfProjectLocation" bindWith="projectLocation"/>
<button label="Browse" action="actionBrowse"/>
:
```

When I update the value of the property from within the bean (such as with an action) the UI does not get updated with the new value.

Comment: Can you verify that the `Action`, `actionBrowse`, has been registered with the `Browse` button?

Comment: actionBrowse is getting called. It creates a FileChooser dialog that returns a path which is assigned to the property projectLocation. Stepping through the code I can see projectLocation changing to the new value but the text field is not updated to reflect it.

Comment: So `bindWith` should make that happen?

Comment: That's what I was expecting but I needed to dispatch a PropertyChangEvent. See my self :( answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to dispatch a `PropertyChangEvent` to the `PropertyChangeListener` on the bean.

```
projectLocation = fc.getSelectedFile().getPath();
PropertyChangeEvent pce = new PropertyChangeEvent(this,
    "projectLocation", projectLocation, fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
PropertyChangeListener[] p = getPropertyChangeListeners();
p[0].propertyChange(pce);
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Swing is single Threaded and all changes must be done on EDT ([EventDispaschThread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)),

2) if you want to update UI, 
- if isn't there EDT, 
- updates camings from BackGround Tasks 
- there aren't Events from [Listeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) (especially from [ActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) or [Action](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html))

a) you have to wrap into invokeLater()

b) not sure but that most of methods should be UI/Look&Feel rellated, then you have to call `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI`([Top-Level Container's Name](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html));